# Xamarin.forms iOS app signed with invalid signature when deploying in debug on device

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, deployment, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Set Apple signing to automatic with correct team for app bundle id
2. Build and run to actual ios device

**Expected Behavior**

App built and signed and debugging on ios device.

**Actual Behavior**

App builds, but during deploy the following error is output in the deploy window and the app is not installed:

ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.XhLS8d/extracted/App.iOS.app : 0xe8008014 (The executable contains an invalid signature.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '[my app path and name here]' on the device '[device name here]': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: ##0xe8008014.

Deployment on physical iPhone worked during the development of the previous version of my APP few months ago.

**Environment**

Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac
Version 17.6.3 (build 421)

Runtime
.NET 7.0.3 (64-bit)
Architecture: X64
Microsoft.macOS.Sdk 13.1.1007; git-rev-head:8afca776a0a96613dfb7200e0917bb57f9ed5583; git-branch:release/7.0.1xx-xcode14.2

Outils de développement Apple
Xcode: 14.3.1 21815
Version : 14E300c

Xamarin.iOS
Version : 16.4.0.6 Visual Studio Community
Synthèse : 97731c92c
Branche : xcode14.3
Date de build : 2023-04-11 22:38:36-0400

Système d’exploitation
Mac OS X 13.4.1
Darwin 22.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0
Thu Jun  8 22:22:22 PDT 2023
root:xnu-8796.121.3~7/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

**What I did in order to fix it**

- Update visual studio, xcode, Mac and iPhone OS
- Deleted ALL development certs on developer.apple
- Deleted ALL provisioning profiles with my APP ID
- Deleted %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning
- Log in as Apple developer in VS settings and connected to Mac
- Opened VS 2022 and selected Automatic Provisioning, it created all things needed to debug
- Open XCode and download all profiles
- As mentionned here [#16190](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16190) I tried to add "EnableCodeSigning" key to "true" in my iOS project file here the code :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|iPhone' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\iPhone\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <MtouchArch>ARM64</MtouchArch>
    <CodesignKey>Apple Development: </CodesignKey>
    <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug>
    <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
    <MtouchInterpreter>-all</MtouchInterpreter>
    <CodesignProvision>VS: XXX.XXXXX.XXXXXXXXX Development</CodesignProvision>
    <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
    <RunWithWarnings>true</RunWithWarnings>
    <CodesignExtraArgs></CodesignExtraArgs>
    <MtouchUseThumb></MtouchUseThumb>
    <IpaPackageName></IpaPackageName>
    <CrashReportingApiKey></CrashReportingApiKey>
    <EnableCodeSigning>True</EnableCodeSigning>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You can try building a new project to see if this project also has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to automatic provisioning, there are two ways to provision the iOS device. You may have a try.

1.[Free provisioning for Xamarin.iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos) through XCode. If you do not have a paid Apple developer account, you could use this way.

2.[Manual provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos). This way is not such convenient as automatic provisioning but I think it is more stable. In this way, you should generate a new provisioning file at Apple Developer portal, remember to include the device you want to deploy.

For more info, you could refer to [Device provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/).